# ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node Module not found

Tags: angular, angular8

Not able to run the angualr application due to below errors.

**ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'G:\Git\myAngularApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'**

System Configuration are:

---

**OS: Windows 7
Node Version: 13.14.0
Angular CLI: 8.0.0**

Please see the below attached errors and help me if anyone knows the solution.
Thank you.

[image: error]

[image: version info]

I tried reinstalling node_modules but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when angular cannot find .angular-cli.json file (Do note there is a dot in the file name). Usually it is a hidden file.

Try these steps first:
Delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json file
npm install
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng serve
If it still produces the same error, then you will actually need .angular-cli.json file.

Default .angular-cli.json file:
Note: This is just a default file, you will need to configure your project settings in this file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "PROJECT_NAME"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```